# error message occur when im trying redirecting the user on server side

Tags: node.js, express

im trying to redirect the user to the dashboard if ever the id is not on database.
but I get an error message saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

my middleware code

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Room = require('./model/room');

module.exports.isOnDB = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  console.log(id);
  const room = Room.findById(id, function (err) {
    console.log('ge');
    //console.log(err.message);
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  next();
};
```

my routes code

```
const { isOnDB } = require('../middleware');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('layouts/boilerplate');
});


router.get('/room/:id', isOnDB, (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room });
});
```

my app.js

```
    const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/', adminRoutes);
```

Comment: You're redirecting and calling `next`, that means you're forwarding the request twice. Try removing the `next` call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not waiting for your `Room.findById` function to finish before calling `next()`.  I would move the `next()` call into the `Room.findById` callback so you can handle both situations - if the id is in the DB and if it isn't.

For example:

```
module.exports.isOnDB = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const room = Room.findById(id, function (err) {
     if (err) {
         // if id is NOT found, or if there's an error, call next()
         console.log(err);
         return next();
     }

    // if the id is found in the DB, then redirect
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```